# Faulty Dynamic memory allocation for larger values

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the code below, i am taking **n** as a user input, and depending on its value i have allocated memory to the pointer array (both **n** and **pointer array** are a part of a structure). The whole code works well for values of **n** below 4, anything 4 or beyond, its giving a segmentation fault while inputting values in the pointer array.

I can imagine that it might be because the memory isn't getting allocated but why its only beyond 4 I don't understand

Here is a snippet where the problem is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// static int n;
typedef struct test_case {
  int n;
  int *test[];
} testCase;

int maxsc(testCase *test_case_ptr);
int find_maximum(int *ptr, int n);

int main() {
  int T;
  int x = 0;
  int temp;
  testCase *test_case_ptr;
  printf("T = ");
  scanf("%d", &T);
  printf("\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
    printf("N = ");
    scanf("%d", &test_case_ptr->n);
    temp = test_case_ptr->n;
    printf("\n");
    test_case_ptr = (testCase *)malloc(sizeof(struct test_case));
    for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
      test_case_ptr->test[i] = malloc(sizeof(int *) * test_case_ptr->n);
    }
    test_case_ptr->n = temp;
    // printf("%d\n", test_case_ptr->n);
    printf("give values\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < test_case_ptr->n; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < test_case_ptr->n; k++) {
        scanf("%d", &test_case_ptr->test[j][k]);
      }
    }
    int max_score = maxsc(test_case_ptr);
    printf("\n");
    printf("The max_score_%d = %d \n", x++, max_score);
}
```

}

Comment: `testCase *test_case_ptr;` You try to use this before initializing it.

Comment: should i use a **memset** to initialize it?

Comment: No need to use `memset()` to initialize a pointer.  The pointer needs to be initialized/assigned to point to valid memory.  Read `n` into an `int` and then allocate, then assign.

Comment: Also, when using a flexible array, you need to alloc the mem for it when you malloc the mem for the struct.

Answer (score 0):

First, you try to use the `test_case_ptr` struct before allocating mem for it. Second, when using a flexible array, you need to alloc the mem for it when you malloc the mem for the struct.

```
scanf("%d", &temp);
// Allocate mem for the struct plus the array
test_case_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test_case) + sizeof(int *) * temp);
test_case_ptr->n = temp;
// Allocate each row in the array
for (int i = 0; i < test_case_ptr->n; i++) {
  test_case_ptr->test[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * test_case_ptr->n);
}
// .....
```

Comment: I am new to tack exchange so it doesnt show my upvote! it works,! Major thanks!

Comment: @ShivaKumar You should be able to click the checkmark below the up/down vote arrows to accept the answer.